# Binning a GigE Camera with OpenCV in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, camera, pixelformat

How can I control horizontal and vertical binning on a camera for 2x2 and 4x4 from a C++ program running on Windows in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Which video i/o backend?

Comment: I am using Basler and TeleDyne Dalsa cameras for which I do not believe there is a specific backend so I have been using CAP_ANY.

Comment: `CAP_ANY` just means it automagically picks one that works. You'll need to go through the list manually and see which one it is. I'd start from the most likely ones, I guess `PVAPI` `GIGANETIX` and maybe `XIAPI` (that might be a long shot)? At least in trunk, I see some binning properties supported by `PVAPI` and `XIAPI`. I'm not sure how well PVAPI talks with other manufacturers cameras (i just have AVT ones), and Ximea API seems like something proprietary too. I guess the giganetix one might be it, although in that case you're out of luck -- at best you've gotta patch openCV to add support.

Comment: Ok thanks I will give those a try